# Using Rails as_json with conditional statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have a file (show.json.erb) in which I'm formatting a model as json.  In my app, Projects have many Steps and many Images, and Steps have many Images.

I'd like to be able to include only a default image for a project, which I'm trying to do using "conditions."  However, it seems to be ignoring the conditions and posting all the images associated with a project.  How do I include only the right images?

```
"projects":
<%= JSON.pretty_generate(@projects.order("updated_at DESC").as_json(only: [:title, :id, 
    :built, :updated_at], include: {images: {only: [:image_path], 
    :conditions=>['Step.find(image.step_id).name.eql? "Project Overview"', true] }  
})).html_safe %>
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by creating a method called image_path in my Projects model:

(I needed the method to return three types of images)

```
  def image_path
    images = Hash.new
    if first_step.images.present?
        images["url"] = first_step.first_image.image_path_url    
        images["preview"] = first_step.first_image.image_path_url(:preview) 
        images["thumbnail"] = first_step.first_image.image_path_url(:thumb) 
    end
    return images
  end
```

Then I edited my JSON to look like this:

```
   "projects":
        <%= JSON.pretty_generate(@projects.order("updated_at DESC").as_json(only: [:title, :id, :built], :methods=> [:image_path, :updated_at_formatted])).html_safe %>
```

This gets rendered like this on my website:

```
    "projects":
                [
      {
        "built": true,
        "id": 115,
        "title": "Video Test",
        "image_path": {
          "url": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/...",
          "preview": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/...",
          "thumbnail": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/..."
        },
        "updated_at_formatted": "07/08/2013 10:31:19"
      },
...]
```

Hope this helps someone else!